# Second td above first td + html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="TableContent">
            <td class="shouldbeunderTableMenu"></td>
            <td class="TableMenu"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see I have a td with class equal to `TableMenu`. I would like to position the td **above** the td with class `shouldbeunderTableMenu`.

So that the first td is vertically positioned under the second td. Image to clarify:

[image]

But how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? Could you not just use two table rows each with a single cell? Or even get rid of the table completely?

Comment: Just switch them in places...

Comment: The html is already created and I don't really have the opportunity to change it (client stuff)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use [before](http://api.jquery.com/before),

```
$(".shouldbeunderTableMenu").before($(".TableMenu"));
```

```js
$(".shouldbeunderTableMenu").before($(".TableMenu"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="TableContent">
            <td class="shouldbeunderTableMenu">1</td>
            <td class="TableMenu">2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

or use [after](http://api.jquery.com/after)

```
$(".TableMenu").after($(".shouldbeunderTableMenu"));
```

```js
$(".TableMenu").after($(".shouldbeunderTableMenu"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="TableContent">
            <td class="shouldbeunderTableMenu">1</td>
            <td class="TableMenu">2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: your code will not work. I think you may have the elements reversed.

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery:

```
$('td.TableMenu').each(function() { $(this).prependTo($(this).parent()); });
```

Or more generally:

```
$('td.TableMenu').each(function() { $(this).before($(this).siblings('.shouldbeunderTableMenu')); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use all that fancy jQuery when you can use css :P

```
td{
    border:1px solid black;
    display:block;    
}
.TableMenu{
    margin-top:-45px;    
}
.shouldbeunderTableMenu{
    margin-top:25px;
}
```

Working example:http://jsfiddle.net/h0pLe8cw/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var shoulder  =  $(".TableContent .shouldbeunderTableMenu");
    var clone = shoulder.clone();
    shoulder.remove();
    $(".TableContent").append(clone);
});
```

Comment: unnecessary use of cloning

Comment: @Alex can you explain why I dont need cloning? thanks

Comment: can you explain why you need it? the question is how to move, not copy/dublicate elements

Comment: but isn't it producing the same result? I'm just wondering why this way is inefficient.

Comment: because youre creating another element and delete the original one. when you want to move your car from a to b do you drive there or buy a new one and destroy the first one? :)

Comment: haha... I actually did that once in the past... Regardless, does `clone` take up too much resources or why is it ineffective?

Comment: depends on what you define as `too much`. everything that is above the necessary is, imho, too much, yes. why complicated when it also works easily?

Comment: guess it seemed like clean code to me. anyway, i will study up on this. thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: all i want to say is: you dont have to clone/ create a new element when you simply can move it in the first place.

Comment: Gotcha. I did like Rohan Kumar's answer above. Cant beat a one-liner.